# Fabric js. Cannot make pattern fill for multiple rects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Good day, I hope someone can give me a hand on this.

I have a for statement, that create and add multiple Rects on fabric js canvas. I need to set texture for each of created rects, so i use the following code.

```js
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  selectable: true,
  hasControls: false,
  borderColor: 'red',
  borderWidth: 2,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true
});

canvas.add(rect);

fabric.util.loadImage('construct/css/img/patterns/1.jpg', function(img) {
  rect.set('fill', new fabric.Pattern({
    source: img,
    repeat: 'repeat'
  }));
});
 Выполнить
```

For some reason, after code execution, not all rects having texture, but only the last one added.

This is realy drives me crazy.

Would appreciate any help on this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is you are using the same variable rect for all your rectangles, and that's why you have pattern just for last object.
For example, you will add 4 rectangles:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: i * 110,
    selectable: true,
    hasControls: false,
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 2,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true
  });

  canvas.add(rect);
}
```

Then you will need to loop through all rectangles and set fill pattern like:

```
fabric.util.loadImage('http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg', function(img) {
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
    obj.set('fill', new fabric.Pattern({
    source: img,
    repeat: 'repeat'
  }));
  });
  
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hxbppf63/)

**WARNING:** if you will have other objects besides rectangles you will need to ignore them by checking object type, or set some sort of your custom shape type to the rectangles.

Comment: Please accept the answer if I answered to your question